# Python - best way to set a column in a 2d array to a specific value

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array, I would like to set a column to a particular value, my code is below. Is this the best way in python?

```
rows = 5
cols = 10

data = (rows * cols) *[0]
val = 10
set_col = 5

for row in range(rows):
    data[row * cols + set_col - 1] = val
```

If I want to set a number of columns to a particular value , how could I extend this

I would like to use the python standard library only

Thanks

Comment: I know you want only the standard library, but numpy was made for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A better solution would be:

```
data = [[0] * cols for i in range(rows)]
```

For the values of `cols = 2`, `rows = 3` we'd get:

```
data = [[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]]
```

Then you can access it as:

```
v = data[row][col]
```

Which leads to:

```
val = 10
set_col = 5

for row in range(rows):
    data[row][set_col] = val
```

Or the more Pythonic (thanks J.F. Sebastian):

```
for row in data:
    row[set_col] = val
```

Comment: There is no need to use explicit row indexes: `for row in data: \n row[col_index] = value`

Answer (score 29):

[NumPy](https://numpy.org/) package provides powerful N-dimensional array object. If `data` is a `numpy` array then to set `set_col` column to `val` value:

```
data[:, set_col] = val
```

Complete Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a.shape = (5,2)
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> a[:,1] = -1
>>> a
array([[ 0, -1],
       [ 2, -1],
       [ 4, -1],
       [ 6, -1],
       [ 8, -1]])
```

Comment: I kept my answer in the confines of the standard library, but I have to say this is the right way to go for any non-trivial uses of arrays.

Comment: In particular, you can do a multi-column assignment easily.  For example, a[:,[0,2]] += [3,5]

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong with the way you're using, except that it would be clearer to name the variable`set_col` than `set_row` since you're setting a column.

So set a number of columns, just wrap it with another loop:

```
for set_col in [...columns that have to be set...]
```

One concern, though: your 2D array is unusual in that it's packed in a 1D array (Python can support 2D arrays via lists of lists as well), so I would wrap it all with methods or functions.

Answer (score 0):

In your case rows and columns are probably interchangeable, i.e. it's matter of semantics which is which. If this is the case, then you could make columns to occupy sequence of cells in `data` list, and then zero them using just:

```
  data[column_start:column_start+rows] = rows * [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

An earlier answer left out a `range`, so you could try the following:

```
cols = 7
rows = 8

data = [[0] * cols for i in range(rows)]

val = 10
set_col = 5

for row in data:
    row[set_col] = val
```

to extend this to a number of columns you could store the column number and it's value in a `dict`. So to set colum 5 to 10 and column 2 to 7:

```
cols = 7
rows = 8

data = [[0] * cols for i in range(rows)]

valdict = {5:10, 2:7}

for col, val in valdict.items():
    for row in data:
        row[col] = val
```

Swapping the rows and columns, as suggested in another answer, makes this slightly simpler:

```
cols = 7
rows = 8

data = [[0] * rows for i in range(cols)]

valdict = {5:10, 2:7}

for col, val in valdict.items():
    data[col] = [val] * rows
```